# Regex phone number

Tags: regex

I'm trying to solve a problem and i figure out that the best solution is to use regex.

I dont have advance knowledge on regex, so I really need your help.

The problem is that I need to identify if a string is phone number or a cell phone the way we use here in Brazil, like this:

The phone number could be in this format:

> 0 + XX + XXXXXXXX = 01121234567

Or

> XX + XXXXXXXX = 1121234567

Or

> XXXXXXXX = 21234567

In this case its a phone number, so it need to start with 2,3,4 or 5

And if its a cell phone it have 9 digits and must start with 9, exclusive, and second digit must be 6,7 or 8:

> 0 + XX + 9XXXXXXXX = 011961234567

Or

> XX + 9XXXXXXXX = 11971234567

Or

> 9XXXXXXXX = 981234567

So, if i get the strings "011984160986", "11984160986" or "984160986", for example, I need to be able to identify that its a cell phone, and the same for phone numbers.

At the same time I must be able to check that string "84160289" its not a valid phone number.

Can anyone ligth me on this problem with a regex?

I not comfortable with use a lot of "ifs" in my code to validate this.

Thanks.

Comment: You say "second digit must be 6,7 or 8" but in the cell phone examples they don't do it.

Comment: My bad, it was wrong

Comment: *"I'm trying to solve a problem and i figure out that the best solution is to use regex."* [Now you have two problems](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski#Attributed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex for the phone number is

```
\b(0?\d\d)?[2345]\d{7}\b
```

The regex for the cell phone number is

```
\b(0?\d\d)?9[678]\d{7}\b
```

The regex for validating both of them at the same time is

```
\b(0?\d\d)?([2345]|9[678])\d{7}\b
```

See demos: [1](https://regex101.com/r/YNXlNj/1), [2](https://regex101.com/r/YNXlNj/2), [3](https://regex101.com/r/YNXlNj/3).

The `\d` escaper works depending on your language. If it does not work, try replacing it with `[0-9]`.

Comment: Yes, the regex was exactly what I need, except one thing: I did some tests, and if I add a big number the regex did 2 matches, like https://regex101.com/r/0BI89u/1 . The \d{7} in the end doesnt mean that its allowed only 7 chars after this?

Comment: @RaphaelTelatim Oh, right. I've updated the answer using word boundaries (see [https://regex101.com/r/0BI89u/2](https://regex101.com/r/0BI89u/2)).

Answer (score 0):

When I start working on a regex, I like to start with the simplest possible approach first.

NOTE 1: I like to use [free spacing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/freespacing.html) regexes. It helps with readability.

NOTE 2: I'm not using `\d` to avoid possible problems with unicode digits. If unicode digits are allowed, then use `\d`.

> 0 + XX + XXXXXXXX = 01121234567

```
0 [0-9]{2} [0-9]{8}
```

> XX + XXXXXXXX = 1121234567

```
[0-9]{2} [0-9]{8}
```

> XXXXXXXX = 21234567

```
[0-9]{8}
```

> In this case its a phone number, so it need to start with 2,3,4 or 5

OK, now we have more restrictions. Let's start to narrow in here?

```
(0 [0-9]{2} [2-5] [0-9]{7} |
   [0-9]{2} [2-5] [0-9]{7} |
            [2-5] [0-9]{7})
```

With so much in common, we can compress that more.

```
(0 [0-9]{2} | [0-9]{2})? [2-5] [0-9]{7}
```

And finally compress again

```
(0? [0-9]{2})? [2-5] [0-9]{7}
```

> And if its a cell phone it have 9 digits and must start with 9, exclusive, and second digit must be 6,7 or 8:
>
> 0 + XX + 9XXXXXXXX = 011961234567

```
0 [0-9]{2} 9 [6-8] [0-9]{7}
```

> XX + 9XXXXXXXX = 11971234567

```
[0-9]{2} 9 [6-8] [0-9]{7}
```

> 9XXXXXXXX = 981234567

```
9 [6-8] [0-9]{7}
```

Combining them works the same

```
(0? [0-9]{2})? 9 [6-8] [0-9]{7}
```

Putting both phone and land lines together

```
((0? [0-9]{2})? [2-5]   [0-9]{7} |
 (0? [0-9]{2})? 9 [6-8] [0-9]{7})
```

This can be compressed to

```
(0? [0-9]{2})? ([2-5] | 9 [6-8]) [0-9]{7}
```

To embed this use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) if that fits your needs.

```
\b (0? [0-9]{2})? ([2-5] | 9 [6-8]) [0-9]{7} \b
```

The final form is similar to the other answer, but I felt it's worthwhile to work the whole process.