# Extract Australian phone numbers from string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match Australian phone numbers. As the numbers can start with 0 or +61 or 61 followed by 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 7 or 8 and then followed by 8 digit number.

```
txt = "My phone number is 0412345677 or +61412345677 or 61412345677"

find_ph = re.find_all(r'(0|\+61|61)[234578]\d{8}', text)
find_ph
```

returns

```
['0', '61']
```

But I want it to return

```
['0412345677', '+61412345677' or '61412345677']
```

Can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I find it very useful using this tool: https://regex101.com/

Comment: You need to create the regex suitable for your problem...

Comment: I suggest you read up on the role of parentheses in regular expressions.

Comment: Also, how about this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43634472/4603295

Comment: @Adriano--doesn't work on OP txt string.

Comment: Use non-grouping parentheses in the regex. Otherwise "find_all" only returns the match in the grouping parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> pattern = r'((?:0|\+61|61)[234578]\d{8})'
>>> find_ph = re.findall(pattern, txt)
>>> print(find_ph)
['0412345677', '+61412345677', '61412345677']
```

The problem you had was that the parentheses around just the prefix part were telling the findall function to only capture those characters, while matching all the rest. (Incidentally it's `findall` not `find_all`, and your string was in the variable `txt`not `text`).

Instead, make that a non-capturing group with (?:0|+61|61). Now you capture the whole of the string that matches the entire pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can using Non-capturing group,

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/hxjzGQ/1)

```
import re

re.findall("(?:0|\+61|61)\d+", text)
```

---

```
['0412345677', '+61412345677', '61412345677']
```

Answer (score 0):

One Solution

```
re.findall(r'(?:0|61|\+61)[2345678]\d{8}', txt)
# ['0412345677', '+61412345677', '61412345677']
```

Explanation

```
(?:0|61|\+61)   Non-capturing group for 0, 61 or +61
(?:0|61|\+61)[2345678]\d{8}  following by one digit except 0, 1, 9
\d{8}           followed by 8 digits
```